# How to upsert/insert records in all tables in an Azure SQL Database with Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, insert-update, multiple-tables, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure SQL database with many tables that I want to update frequently with any change made, be it an update or an insert, using Azure Data Factory v2.
There is a section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal) that explains how to do this.
However, the example is about two tables, and for each table a TYPE needs to be defined, and for each table a Stored Procedure is built.
I don't know how to generalize this for a large number of tables.
Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: You can put all the tables and it's change logic in a single `StoreProcedure`.Then use a single StoreProcedure Activity (SSIS) to achieve it Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-stored-procedure-activity

Answer (score 1):

You can follow my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69896947/7392069 but I don't know how to generalise creation of table types and stored procedures, but at least the metadata table of the metadata driven copy task provides a lot of comfort to achieve what you need.